# Add tracking info into WooCommerce order via Rest API

Tags: rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to update a WooCommerce order using **Update an Order** in the Woo API ([API Doc](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#update-an-order))

I want to add the following information into an order:

- tracking provider
- tracking number
- tracking URL

I can add/update information inside of the **"meta data"** array, however, I can't seem to figure out how to update the **"_wc_shipment_tracking_items"** ***"value"*** array that is located within the **"meta data"** array.

So essentially, I want to update/create an array within an array. For a visual understanding, see (highlighted is where I want to update):

[image]

I’ve tried many variations, but the following is as far as I've come... I can’t seem to figure it out:

```
 "meta_data": [
    {
        "key": "_wc_shipment_tracking_items" 
            "value": [
                {
                    "key": "custom_tracking_provider",
                    "value": "postage service"
                },
                {
                    "key": "tracking_number",
                    "value": "aaa123"
                },
                {
                    "key": "custom_tracking_link",
                    "value": "https://google.com/"
                }
            ]
    }
]
```

I hope someone can help me out, or point me in the right direction. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question can be found on this page:
https://woocommerce.com/document/shipment-tracking/

under 'REST API Support' you will find this piece of code that you need:

```
curl -X POST https://example.com/wp-json/wc-shipment-tracking/v3/orders/645/shipment-trackings \
-u consumer_key:consumer_secret \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
      "custom_tracking_provider": "Custom",
      "custom_tracking_link": "https://example.com?q=%1$s",
      "tracking_number": "12345678"
    }'
```